# Why Pair plot is taking up the target variable into consideration?

Tags: seaborn

I am working on [Haberman's cancer survival data set](https://www.kaggle.com/gilsousa/habermans-survival-data-set).

I tried to visualize the pair plot with features as AGE, `Op_Year`, `axil_nodes_det` and target variable as `Surv_status`. I expect 12 plots but getting 16 including plots with `Surv_stautus` which is my target variable
here is my code:

```
sns.set_style("whitegrid");
sns.pairplot(patients, hue="Surv_status", size=3);
```

Comment: Have you Dropped that column temporarily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe because Surv_status is number.
there are two solution:

1. define variables:

   ```
   sns.set_style("whitegrid"); sns.pairplot(patients, hue="Surv_status",vars=["AGE", "Op_Year", "axil_nodes_det"], size=3);
   ```
2. change target value to a string:

   ```
   patients['Surv_status'] = patients['Surv_status'].astype(str)
   ```

or

```
    patients['Surv_status'] = patients['Surv_status'].str
```